# Which label is a better option CSV or attachments?

Tags: labels

Referring to the image below, should I use 'CSV' (Comma Separated Values) as a label or something else?

[image]

Comment: Is this column used to record the number of CSV files imported? If you can clarify the purpose it will be easier to come up with a label.

Comment: I want to extract list from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **importing data** from a CSV file, and it specifically has to be in a CSV format (no .xls for example), then you should use "CSV" as the label.  If it is not specifically a CSV format, then you should rather use something like "imported" or "files imported".

If you are **attaching a file** to some document (think of an email attachment here), then you should use "attachments" as the term.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use "CSV" to show the source from which e-mail addresses have been imported. In this case I suggest "From Files" instead of "CSV" and "Import from CSV file" instead of "CSV file import".